# is there any limit for number of events i can create while using google-calendar-api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

My application sync shifts details of a user to google calendar using google-calendar-api,
for example, I can sync data from 24/08/2021 to 24/08/2021 and it will show in the user's google calendar as an event, but the application throws error for higher day ranges(for eg more than 3 months data syncing).is there any limit for google-calendar-api usage? if so what is the action needed from my end to support a higher limit of data synicng.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. i will check